# How can I update a stream from within a StreamBuilder?

Tags: android, flutter

Thank you very much in advance for your help! Please let me know if the question is not clear i would be happy to add more details if needed.

I have a Finite State Machine that handles some audio recognition. This FSM is wrapped by a "manager" whose job is to handle the state transitions (processState, nextState). The FSM manager exposes a stream which is updated every time nextState is called

***FSM/Manager layout***

```dart
class FSM_Manager{
StreamController<RecognitionState> _stateStream =
      StreamController<RecognitionState>();
  Sink<RecognitionState> get _inState => _stateStream.sink;
  Stream<RecognitionState> get outState => _stateStream.stream;
  RecognitionState _currentState, _previousState;
 
void setState(RecognitionState state) {
    _previousState = _currentState;
    _currentState = state;
    _addCurrentStateToStream();
  }

  void _addCurrentStateToStream() {
    _inState.add(_currentState);
  }

  Future nextState() async {
    _currentState.nextState(this);
  }

  Future processState(itemToRecognize) async {
    await _currentState.processState(itemToRecognize);
  }
}

abstract class BaseState {
  RecognitionStateID get stateID; //enum with each state's ID
  Future processState(itemToRecognize);
  Future nextState(FSM_Manager manager);
}

class FSM_State1 implements BaseState{
 bool isSuccess = false;
 void processState(itemToRecognize) async {
 isSuccess = await performRecognition(itemToRecognize);  
}
 void nextState (FSM_Manager fsmManager) {
   if(isSuccess){
     // go to next State
     fsmManager.setState(NEXT_STATE);
   } else {
     //go to some other state
     fsmManager.setState(SOME_OTHER_STATE);
   }
 }
}

class FSM_State2 implements BaseState{
  bool isSuccess = false;
  void processState(itemToRecognize) async {
    isSuccess = await performRecognition(itemToRecognize); 
 }
 void nextState () {
   if(isSuccess){
     // go to next State
   } else {
     // go to another State
   }
 }
}
```

I have a screen (Stateful Widget) which uses a StreamBuidler to listen to the "outState" stream in order to rebuild the screen with the information in the new State.

***Stateful Widget***

```dart
class _RecognitionScreenState extends State<RecognitionScreen> {
  ItemToRecognize item;
  var currStateiD;
  FSM_Manager _fsmManager;
  RecognitionScreenState(
      ItemToRecognize item, FSM_Manager fsmManager) {
    this.item = item;
    this._fsmManager = fsmManager;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String outString = '';

    return StreamBuilder<RecognitionState>(
        stream: _stateContext.outState,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<RecognitionState> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            outString = snapshot.data.stateID.toString();

            return Text(outString);
          } else {
            return Text('');
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Now, I do not know where/how to call processState and nextState from, I cant do it from the build method so i Tried to use initState() and didUpdateWidget in the StatefulWidget so that the states are processed in the beginning and after every build respectively. This approach didnt work, the nextState method was never called. I feel like im missing something trivial but i just dont see where to call those functions from outside of the Stateful Widget in order to trigger a rebuild only after the state has changed

Thanks again for your help

***EDIT***

I apologize for the confusion,

- I added the BaseState definition (just an abstract class with some method so that i dont forget to implement them)
- the nextState method takes an FSM_Manager as a parameter and calls setState on success or failure and sets the next state
- the States "implement" the BaseState class, they dont "extend" it

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to tell from your code because I don't know what your BaseState does but inside your builder - presumably from some event or callback - you would do:

```
inState.add(<--Some RecognitionState-->);
```

This would trigger the StreamBuilder to rebuild.

If everything else in your code is put together properly.

Comment: that is correct, i made some edits to hopefully make it a bit more clear. the nextStates would set the state by calling setState on the FSM_Manager. Im just uncertain as to what mechanism to use to to call these functions.
I apologize for the confusion, thanks for your comment

Comment: I would expect that somewhere you are listening to a stream of audio events from the platform. Wherever that listener is it would need either direct access to your inState sink or a closure that calls it. In other words, underneath all of this code, what drives changes in this manager? Listen to that and feed those events to your manager with your sink.